# Using a nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, nested, android-linearlayout

**SOLVED: The layout_height parameter was set to Match_parent in the buttonbar definition. Changed to wrap_content.**

I'm currently working on a new App which has a series of buttons at the top of the main screen. the "buttonBar" XML defines a linearLayout and is later nested within another linearLayout.

The buttons appear fine and work however if I then put a text view beneath the include statement the text does not appear. I think that it is actually appearing behind the buttons. I assumed that because it was within a parent linearLayout that it would appear after the included (nested) nested layout.

please could someone explain why this is not occurring and point me in the right direction to solve it.

much appreciated, 
M

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/buttonheader"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="TextView" 
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:textColor="#ffffff">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you solved your issue yourslef, post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `height` and `width` of the included layout  `buttonheader`

SO that you can see this included layout in your layout

Comment: Is there a way of setting these so that they will work on all phones? I've only got a HTC desire that I'm developing on and I'm worried that explicitly setting such parameters may reduce compatibility.

Comment: You can use relative layout it will help you much about screen problem